# Load fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I am writing tests for a model `Friends::New`. My `new_test.rb` file looks like :

```
require 'test_helper'

class Friends::New < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :news.yml
end
```

My `news.yml` is located in `test/fixtures/friends/news.yml`. But during  running test, it tries to find `news.yml` in `test/fixtures/`. How do I tell it to search the yml file in `test/fixtures/friends`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell rails about it explicitly.

```
class Friends::New < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  set_fixture_class 'friends/news' => Friends::New
end
```

Read [`set_fixture_class`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods/set_fixture_class).

> Sets the model class for a fixture when the class name cannot be inferred from the fixture name.

Comment: Will it be set_fixture_class 'friends/new' or set_fixture_class 'friends/news' ?

Comment: I am accessing first test case as @new_friends = news(:one)  and it throws an error.